# I'm getting an API error

Tags: support, api

I've set up my app with the ID 4921.

I've added the redirect_uri to be `stackexchange.com`.

But when I go to this page:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=4921&scope=read_inbox&redirect‌​‌​_uri=ht‌​tp://stackexchange.com
```

I get an error:

```
error description: expected redirect_uri parameter
```

even though I've included the parameter, here:

```
&redirect‌​‌​_uri=ht‌​tp://stackexchange.com
```

My app page:

[image]

What have I done wrong?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21826979#21826979 is mine and @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ's attempt at bug fixing

Comment: (my failed attempt :P)

Answer (score 4):

Just changed the `redirect_uri` in the app page and it gave a different error. Then changed it back and I'm authenticated.

```
New URL: https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=4921&scope=read_inbox&redirect_uri=http://stackexchange.com
Old URL: https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=4921&scope=read_inbox&redirect‌​‌​_uri=ht‌​tp://stackexchange.com
```

Comment: Wow. The standard "Have you turned it off and on again" (kind of) solution :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ yeah, but like turned on and off 3 times and make a mistake half way through :p

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I just used the old URL (the bottom one here) and it still doesn't work... There are invisible chars, it's like 15 chars longer

Comment: But the new url works right?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ yeah so idk what's wrong

Comment: Yeah - they're exactly the same! It's really weird - but at least you've got it *working* now :) (although we don't know *how* ;P)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ ahh yes, gotcha. Was getting back garbled text from urllib, using requests now.

Comment: yeah - requests is so much easier - I've been trying it out since yesterday.. but I don't have anything to make :|